# Wicket Component hierarchy - getParent()

Tags: java, components, wicket

I did an experiment. First I want to state the html:

```
<form wicket:id="form">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="border: 1px solid;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr wicket:id="row">
                    <td wicket:id="column" style="border: 1px solid #3A6395">
                        <div wicket:id="div">
                            <span wicket:id="panel"></span>
                            <span wicket:id="tooltip"><span wicket:id="tooltipPanel"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<wicket:fragment wicket:id="labelFragment">
    <span wicket:id="value"></span>
</wicket:fragment>
<wicket:fragment wicket:id="linkFragment">
    <a href="" wicket:id="link">
        <span wicket:id="value"></span>
    </a>
</wicket:fragment>
```

The java:

```
private class ReportDisplayByUserWithTaskTypeSortForm extends Form {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 10162L;

        public ReportDisplayByUserWithTaskTypeSortForm(String id) {
            super(id);
            setOutputMarkupId(true);
            addComponent();
        }

        private void addComponent() {           
            ListView row = new ListView("row", new LoadableDetachableModel() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 10164L;

                @Override
                protected Object load() {
                    return getUserMonitorMap();
                }
            }) {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 10165L;

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem rowItem) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    List<? extends Element> columnMap = (List<Element>) rowItem.getModelObject();
                    ListView column = new ListView("column", columnMap) {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 10166L;

                        @Override
                        protected void populateItem(ListItem columnItem) {
                            Element element = (Element) columnItem.getModelObject();

                            WebMarkupContainer div = new WebMarkupContainer("div");
                            Label value = new Label("value");
                            Fragment fragment = null;

                            if (element instanceof TaskTypeLabelElement) {
                                fragment = new Fragment("panel", "linkFragment", this);

                                AjaxLink link = new AjaxLink("link") {

                                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10163L;

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                                        sortAsc = !sortAsc;
                                        doSort();                                       
                                        target.addComponent(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());                                      
                                    }
                                };
                                link.add(value);
                                fragment.add(link);
                            } else {
                                fragment = new Fragment("panel", "labelFragment", this);
                                fragment.add(value);
                            }

                            // some other code goes here

                            columnItem.add(div);
                        }
                    };
                    rowItem.add(column);
                }
            };

            add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

The link within the fragment is instantiating as:

```
AjaxLink link = new AjaxLink("link") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 10163L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println(this);
            System.out.println(this.getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());
            System.out.println(this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent());
        }
    };
```

The output for System.out.println :

```
15:58:17,476 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = link]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = panel]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = div]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = 0]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = column]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = 0]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = row]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [MarkupContainer [Component id = form]]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] [Page class = info.release.wicket.ReportDisplayByUserWithTaskTypeSort, id = 4, version = 0]
15:58:17,477 INFO  [STDOUT] null
```

My questions are:

- What is the meaning of "Component id = 0" after "Component id = div" and "Component id = column", what is this component?
- What is the meaning of "id = 4, version = 0" of the second last line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The components with ID 0 are the `ListItem`s, their ID is their index in the containing `ListView`.

Each page is assigned an ID per session ("id = 4"), see the "Identity" paragraph in the [API documention of Page](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Page.html).

Each page may be versioned for back button support ("version = 0"), see the "Back Button" paragraph in the [API documention of Page](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Page.html). If enabled, multiple versions per page are stored in the session. New versions are usually triggered by form submits. You may try it with the [forminput example](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/forminput/), submit the form multiple times with different values, take a look at the URL (where you can see the increasing version) and try the back button of your browser.