# how to access html element which doesn't have a wicket:id

Tags: wicket

I am new to wicket ,Please someone help me with a thought. I have a logic around a checkbox to display or not to display.
Problem:
when the logic of not to display a checkbox is on , which is by adding a display:none to the checkbox element dynamcially in code , there is a white space because of td surronding the checkbox.

my html looks like

```
<span wicket:id="checkgroup">
<table>
<tr wicket:id="srow" >
<td><input type="checkbox" wicket:id="scheck"/></td>
<td><img wicket:id="sicon"></img></td>
</tr>
</table>
</span>
```

so in code I have if else logic for adding a display:none to check box element which removes the checkbox from the view which looks like the below

```
<span wicket:id="checkgroup">
<table>
<tr wicket:id="srow" >
<td><input type="checkbox" wicket:id="scheck" style="display:none"/></td>
<td><img wicket:id="sicon"></img></td>
</tr>
</table>
</span>                     

final CheckGroup<Scope> checkGroup = new CheckGroup<>("checkGroup", 
new ArrayList<> ());    
ListView<Scope> listView = new ListView<Scope>
("srow", sList); 
@Override
protected void populateItem(final ListItem<S> item)
{
  Check<S> check = new Check<>("scheck", item.getModel(), checkGroup);
  if(defaultscope)
  {
     check.add(new AttributeModifier("style","display:none"));
  }
  item.add(check);
}
```

so now my checkbox disappears but the surrounding td stays and causing a white space in display.

Any ideas on how to approach this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: move the display:none to the td if you want it to hide as well.

Comment: but i dont have a wicket:id on it to access it on java side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137269/wicket-component-hierarchy-getparent  I think this'll do it for you.  getParent() - you have to dig down a little to get to it - there's probably an explanation in docs.

Comment: sure.. Thankyou so much :) will try it..

Comment: Have you tried item.setVisible(false) ? I'm not 100% sure but this should remove all row markup.

Comment: I just want to remove the checkbox so want to remove/ block the display of the first td in each row populated.

Comment: So what about giving a wicket:id to the first td and using a WebMarkupContainer to wrap your checkbox?   in this way you will be able to move display:none to the td

Comment: wow.. Thankyou so much enclosing it in a WebMarkupContainer worked. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<wicket:enclosure>` to remove html if the referenced child is not present. [wicket enclosure.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket%27s+XHTML+tags#Wicket'sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket:enclosure)

Your code in populateItem could look like this:

```
Check<S> check = new Check<>("scheck", item.getModel(), checkGroup);
  if(defaultscope)
  {
     check.setVisible(false);
  }
  item.add(check);
```

Your markup would look like this:

```
<tr wicket:id="srow" >
<wicket:enclosure>
  <td><input type="checkbox" wicket:id="scheck"/></td>
</wicket:enclosure>
<td><img wicket:id="sicon"></img></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Just tried enclosing it in a WebMarkupContainer it worked. Will try this enclosure too.. Thankyou all for helping me out.

Comment: Yes.. <wicket:enclosure> worked too. Thankyou so much.